# dynamic table in android studio

Tags: android-studio

i need help to create a table in android studio,please see my code and help me...this code has error when i want to run it in my device!

```
TableLayout table=new TableLayout(this);

public void _start(View v) {
    CreateTable();
}
public void CreateTable() {
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        TableRow groupCells = new TableRow(this);
        for(int column=0;column<3;column++) {
            TextView cell = CreateCells(row, column);

            groupCells.addView(cell);
        }
        table.addView(groupCells);
    }
}

private TextView CreateCells(int row, int column) {
    TextView cell = new TextView(this);
    cell.setId(Integer.valueOf(row + "," + column));
    cell.setWidth(20);
    cell.setHeight(20);
    cell.setText("");
    cell.setX((findViewById(R.id._table).getWidth()/2)-(20*row)+(cell.getWidth()/2));
    cell.setY((findViewById(R.id._table).getHeight()/2)-(20*column)+(cell.getHeight()/2));
    cell.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return cell;
}
```

and i have this errors:

java.lang.NullPointerException   at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformHeight(LinearLayout.java:1380)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1368)   at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)   at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:464)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)   at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:476)   at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)

and i dont know what is this!
please help me...

Comment: please post the error. :)

Comment: @Bob when i run it,my device give force stop error to me